# Can anyone recommend the best textbooks for students learning UX and UI design?

Tags: ux-field, ux-designer, learning, recommendations

I've just started studying UX and UI design online, but could really benefit from having some good, comprehensive textbooks to refer to. Can anyone recommend the best books for students? Books that cover each discipline in detail. It would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi Emma, I wish this was a place where you can also get book recommendations but it is unfortunately considered off topic for this site. I understand the rationale, still I wished for a good thread on this. But searching this site will give you plenty of (closed) questions with answers. If you are interested why book recommendations are considered off topic, please read e.g. https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/986/can-we-reopen-this-question-what-needs-to-change/988#988 or https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1391/so-what-exactly-is-off-topic-for-ux-stackexchange/1410#1410

Answer (score 2):

I've found these to be helpful:

- About Face by Alan Cooper,
- Designing for the Digital Age by Kim Goodman,
- Lean UX by Jeff Gothelf & Josh Seiden,
- books from A Book Apart.

Happy reading!

Comment: There's an existing long thread on here. Use the search.